# PreDestroy аннотация, сравнение с finalise()

Tags: java, spring

Является ли использование, @PreDestroy плохой практикой(как с finalize)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, если уж проводить аналогию между обработчиком событий жизненного цикла SpringBean и финализатором POJO, то проводить её надо между `@PreDestroy` и `finalize()`. Во-вторых, нет, не является. Чтобы понять это, достаточно знать почему не рекомендуется использовать `finalize()`:

1. Его вызов вообще не гарантируется;
2. При его вызове объект может создать ссылку на самого себя и предотвратить собственную сборку;
3. При вызове метода `finalize()` класса не произойдёт вызова этого же метода у суперкласса, что в некоторых случаях может приводить к неправильному освобождению ресурсов;
4. Исключения выброшенные в финализаторе будут потеряны;
5. Он замедляет сборку мусора. Если верить Блоху, то примерно в 430 раз.

В то же время `@PreDestroy` вообще не имеет отношения к сборке мусора, не влияет на производительность и в целом ведёт себя в полном соответствии с правильными архитектурными принципами.

Comment: да, верная поправка, описался, спасибо за ответ

Comment: Когда в таком случаем вызывается PreDestroy, если не перед утилизацией объекта?

Comment: В момент, когда объект перестаёт быть SpringBean'ом, то есть удаляется из контекста. При этом удалиться из кучи он может только при следующей сборке мусора или вообще не удалиться, если на него сохраняется ссылка в программе. Когда конкретно бин удаляется из контекста, зависит от его области видимости. Если это request scope, то в конце запроса. Если singleton, то при удалении контекста, что обычно происходит при завершении программы.

Comment: топ, спасибо !))